# Find $a,b,c $ so the matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I am supposed to find the values of $a,b,c \in R$ for which the matrix can be diagonalized.

$\begin {bmatrix}
1 && 0 && c \\
1 && a && b \\
0 && 0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}$

I know it can be diagonalized if it has 3 linear independent eigenvectors, but that job seems too complicated in this case. 
I am not sure how to approach this problem, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you know about diagonalizable matrices? What properties must a matrix have in order to be diagonalizable? In particular, what must be true about the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a diagonalizable matrix? Based on that information, you should be able to solve this using the characteristic equation.

Comment: @Vyas I added it to the question. I know that a matrix is diagonalizable iff it has $n $ linearly independent vectors.

Comment: You can start by computing eigenvalues. If you have 3 distinct eigenvalues, then you are already done. If you have <3 (which is the case here), you have to check on the dimension of the eigenspaces corresponding to the eigenvalues of multiplicity > 1. Does that help?

Comment: Sure, I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Implied in your question and your response to the comments is that you’re trying to diagonalize via an eigenbasis. There are other ways to diagonalize a matrix besides this.

Comment: Yes, so I was wondering if there was an easier way to approach this problem..

Comment: That depends on what sort of diagonalization is meant in the problem you’ve been given to solve.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Starting point:

$$\begin {vmatrix}
1-\lambda && 0 && c \\
1 && a-\lambda && b \\
0 && 0 && 1-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} = (a-\lambda) \begin {vmatrix}
1-\lambda  && c \\
0 &&  1-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=(a-\lambda)(1-\lambda)^2$$

You can consider two cases

Case 1. $a =1$ and

Case 2.  $a \neq 1$.

Let $\lambda=1$ and see how many eigenvectors corresponds to it.

That is study the nullity of the matrix

$$\begin {bmatrix}
1-\lambda && 0 && c \\
1 && a-\lambda && b \\
0 && 0 && 1-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagonalize a matrix, you want to be able to utilize row operations such that you only end up with values along the diagonal. An easy case is $a = 1, c, b = 0$. Try plugging in and using row operations to simplify the matrix to see why and see if you can generalize this.