# Values of a,b,c that make a matrix diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

For which, if any, values of $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ is the matrix

[image]

diagonalizable?

The Eigenvalues are easy enough. I get $\lambda=1$ (With an algebraic multiplicity of $2$) and $\lambda=c$ (With an algebraic multiplicity of $1$). I'm not really sure how to proceed though.

I could get the eigenvectors by imposing restrictions on the eigenvalues but that's a very painful process and I am not sure if this is the best way too approach this... Any suggestions?

Comment: Check first the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=1$.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321160/find-a-b-c-so-the-matrix-is-diagonalizable) (works the same way).

Comment: A diagonalizable matrix has the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ be equal to the algebraic multiplicity. The easiest way to calculate is to check if the rank of $M - \lambda I$ (the number of linearly independent columns or rows of $M - \lambda I$)   is equal to $n$ minus the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$, where $n = 3$ is the dimension of the $M$, and $\lambda$ goes over the distinct eigenvalues of $M$.

Comment: @user3257842 I was going to answer but your comment beats me. Please convert the comment to an answer noting that a nonzero matrix has rank 1 iff each row is a multiple of one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Find the minimal polynomial of $M$. $M$ will be diagonalisable if and only if the minimal polynomial is a product of linear factors.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.